# Definition of a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I'm a little confused by [Wikipedia's definition of a regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Language):

> The collection of regular languages over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is defined recursively as follows:
>
> - The empty language $\emptyset$ is a regular language.
> - For each $a \in \Sigma$ ($a$ belongs to $\Sigma$), the singleton language ${a}$ is a regular language.
> - If $A$ and $B$ are regular languages, then $A \cup B$ (union), $A \cdot B$ (concatenation), and $A^\ast$ (Kleene star) are regular languages.
> - No other languages over $\Sigma$ are regular.

This seems defines a regular language as any set that contains a finite number of unique elements, though the set can be countably infinite (it's worth noting that the article doesn't explicitly state that $\left\vert{\Sigma}\right\vert$ is finite in the definition), i.e., a regular language is any set $S$

$$
\left\vert{S}\right\vert \le \left\vert{\infty}\right\vert, {S} \in \Sigma \\  
\left\vert{\Sigma}\right\vert \lt \left\vert{\infty}\right\vert
$$

I think this is correct because the union, concatenation or Kleene star of a singleton that is part of a finite set or the empty set must be also part of that set, even when operated on recursively.

It's been a fair while since I did any maths, and even longer since I've touched set theory. Have I completely misread Wikipedia's definition? If so, how? If I haven't how is a regular language different from my definition?

Comment: Kleene star gives you an infinite set for any $A \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I don't think I'm disputing that anywhere @G.Bach. Assuming that $A$ is finite it gives you a countably infinite set rather than an uncountable one though.

Comment: I don't understand how a set can contain "a finite number of unique elements, though the set can be countably infinite" is what I meant to address.

Comment: As I say it's been a long time @G.Bach... but it seems that if $A = \{a\}$ then $A \cdot A$ performed recursively and infinitely will have one unique value, $a$, but infinite elements. It's countable because you know there's one unique value.

Comment: What do you mean by "the union, concatenation or Kleene star of a singleton that is part of a finite set or the empty set must be also part of that set, even when operated on recursively."?  This is false. I think what you mean to say is that regular languages are closed under these operations: that applying any of them to regular sets always produces another regular set.

Comment: @Ben: If arbitrary infinite concatenation were allowed, you would be right, but it is not. You may only concatenate the *same* language an infinite number of times (Kleene star).

Answer (score 3):

Regular languages over a finite alphabet are always countable: indeed, $\Sigma^*$ is countable. However, not every subset of $\Sigma^*$ is regular. This is because the set of regular languages is only *finitely* additive rather than $\sigma$-additive. That means that if $A_1,\ldots,A_\ell$ are regular then so is $A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_\ell$, but the same isn't true for an *infinite* sequence. Indeed, every subset of $\Sigma^*$ can be written as an infinite sum of singletons (sets of size $1$), which are regular, but not all subsets of $\Sigma^*$ are regular. For example, the following subset of $\{0,1\}^*$ isn't: $\{ 0^n 1^n : n \geq 0 \}$.

You define a regular language as one which has a *finite number of unique elements*. Unfortunately, you don't define what these *unique elements* are, so your definition is vague at best. Regular languages have other definitions than the one given by Wikipedia - for example, they are the languages accepted by *deterministic finite automata*, by *non-deterministic finite automata*, and by Turing machines running in time $o(n\log n)$. Each of these has a finite number of *states*, which might correspond to your *unique elements*. A third approach defines a regular language as one having finitely many Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes (two words $x,y \in \Sigma^*$ are equivalent with respect to a language $L$ if for all $z \in \Sigma^*$, $xz \in L$ iff $yz \in L$).

Here is a Wikipedia-like definition of the regular languages (both definitions are the same for finite $\Sigma$). It is the smallest collection of languages which:

1. Contains all singletons $\{a\}$ for $a \in \Sigma$.
2. Closed under finite unions and intersections, under complementation, under concatenation, and under Kleene star.

Every regular language has a "proof" of its being regular which comes from applying the operations above. In the case of the Wikipedia definition, this proof is a *regular expression*, which is why they chose their particular definition. For example, $0^*1^* + 1^*0^*$, the language of "monotone" sequences over $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, can be derived as follows from Wikipedia's rules:

1. $0$ is regular (singleton axiom).
2. $0^*$ is regular (Kleene star applied to (1)).
3. $1$ is regular (singleton axiom).
4. $1^*$ is regular (Kleene star applied to (3)).
5. $0^*1^*$ is regular (concatenation of (2) and (4)).
6. $1^*0^*$ is regular (concatenation of (4) and (2)).
7. $0^*1^* + 1^*0^*$ is regular (union of (5) and (6)).

My rules are more permissive: they allow complementation and intersection. You can try to prove that both definitions are equivalent - this is quite difficult from these definitions, but becomes much easier using either DFAs (deterministic finite automata) or Myhill-Nerode relations.

Comment: Ok, wow... :-). To fixate on what seems to be the salient point I'm wrong because not all subsets of $\Sigma^*$ are regular. Doesn't this mean that Wikipedia is missing things? Because, an alphabet $\Sigma$ can be defined as a set of singletons $\Sigma = \{\{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \{...\}, \{a_n\}\}$. The concatenation of each singleton is $\Sigma$ and the Kleene star of any concatenation under $\Sigma$ is a regular language?

Comment: The alphabet is not a set of singletons, rather it is a union of singletons $\Sigma = \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$.

Comment: Wikipedia's definition is perfectly fine, it corresponds to regular expressions. When $|\Sigma| \geq 2$, not every subset of $\Sigma^*$ can be represented as a regular expression - indeed, only countably many subsets can be so represented, yet there are uncountably many subsets.

Comment: @Yuval: thanks. If the alphabet $\Sigma$ is countably infinite, is $\Sigma$ not a regular language? Neither is $\Sigma^*$? Same answers when $\Sigma$ is uncountable?

Comment: @Tim Usually only finite $\Sigma$ are considered, but if you insist on infinite $\Sigma$ and the same syntax, then $\Sigma$ is not a regular language when $\Sigma$ is infinite.